# Not able to set ACL of score public android parse

Tags: acl

I am working on android app which save score of users in result table in Parse. Now if I want to access the score of users to calculate rank via cloud code I am not able to get it. I guess the reason is ACL, which is not public. And if I manually set the ACL to public read and write for a row, I am able to get the score for that row. So to make that rank code working I have to manually set the ACL to public, which doesn't make any sense. Please help me out.

```
result.put("name", user);
result.put("score", score);
result.put("mobile", out[2]);
ParseACL acl=new ParseACL();
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
result.saveEventually();
```

I tried this but still not working. :(

my cloud code for rank is as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("rank", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("Result");
var score=request.params.score;
query.find({
  success: function(results)
   {
    var tmp;
    var a=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
     {
      tmp=parseInt(results[i].get("score"),10);
      a[i]=tmp;
    }
    a[i]=score;
    a.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++)
    {
        if(a[k]==score)
            break;
    }
    response.success(k+1);
  },
  error:function() 
  {
    response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the acl for the user

```
result.put("name", user);
result.put("score", score);
result.put("mobile", out[2]);
ParseACL acl=new ParseACL();
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
result.setACL(acl);    /*updated here*/
result.saveEventually();
```